# Difference between TLC272CP and TLC272CDR

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, packages, texas-instruments

I was using an operational amplifier in my project from Texas Instruments. The series is TLC272. There are many different models. Could someone tell me the significance or the meaning of CP or CDR in different types of TLC272?

Can you please explain which one is better and how does it make a difference? And also what is a reel?

Comment: If you are soldering or wiring by hand then buy the 8 pin DIP.  Much easier.  If it's a mass production pcb, with limited space then buy the surface mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different packages for the IC. Page 2 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlc272) shows that CP is a plastic DIP package, and CDR is a small outline package. The R at the end means the ICs come in a reel; if there is no R then they come in tubes.

[image]

Performance may depend on the package -- you'll have to check the electrical characteristics in the datasheet to see what the differences are and if they matter to you (the package will be listed at the top of the electrical characteristics table). The package choice is mostly dependent on which you would prefer to use.

Reels are used for large quantities. If you only need a couple hundred (or less) units then you just need tubes. There is no difference in performance between tubes vs. reels -- it's just a difference in how the ICs are shipped.

This is what a reel of ICs looks like:

[image]

This is what a tube of ICs looks like:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am a noob to this. Can you please explain which one is better and how does it make a difference? And also what is a reel?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvI6s9dVdvU

Comment: The CP and CD types should be identical electrically, but different physically.  The CP Plastic DIP is the conventional through-hole package that you would use on a plastic breadboard.  The CD is a smaller surface-mount package.  There should be drawings near the end of the datasheet that show the available packages.